# Is there a way to add to timestamp one second in the next row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I defined my timestamp as default start time:

```
CREATE TABLE testTABLE(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    TS TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT '1998-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I need from now on every next row one more second 
I mean the data of ts will be:

```
1998-01-01 00:00:00
1998-01-01 00:00:01
1998-01-01 00:00:02
etc.
```

What can i do?

Comment: Your task is: 1) Each time when new record inserted set `ts` field in this new record +1 second to previous record; 2) Each time when new record inserted create some predefined amount of records with 1 second gap in `ts` field starting from the value in inserted record. 3) Something else (specify).

Comment: It seems like you want to pre-populate a table where each row will have +1 second increase from the previous row. If that's true, you'll generate a total of 86,400 rows per day and approximately 31,536,000 total rows per year. May we know the reason behind this approach and maybe we can think of a different way to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If TS is timestamp column and you need it to be unique, Why not just Use default as NOW(). Your updated `CREATE TABLE` statement would be -

```
CREATE TABLE testTABLE(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    TS TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT NOW());
```

Comment: I need a defined timestamps. start from '1998-01-01 00:00:00' and one second more for next row

Answer (score 0):

A trigger should do it

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON testTABLE
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.TS = SELECT MAX(TS) + INTERVAL 1 SECOND FROM testTABLE;
END
```

What it does: after the insertion of a row in your table, it takes the MAX(TS) in the table, and add 1 second to it, and then assign this value to the TS of the currently inserted row.

Comment: I try to do this but after that I can't enter any new row.